# How to implement multiple sections in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make tableView with multiple section but i do not want to use dictionary i have an array which contains 3 rows and each row has title,description and userName.

Since there are 3 rows in an array, I want 3 sections in tableview one for each and each section should have 3 rows; like

1. title
2. description
3. userName

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
         return [self.listOfdata count];
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewnumberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 3;
   }
   ```

How can I write cellForRowAtIndexPath method to get desired result?

Comment: `indexPath.row % 3` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should work for you.

Comment: Seems like you are already half way there. What problems do you have building the cells?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already go right way. Now you just implement your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You can implement like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier"];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.yourListTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.yourListDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    } else  {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.yourListName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In my case I create default cell on storyboard. Depend your way create cell it will have some difference.

Answer (score 1):

Imaging you have 3 arrays as you said which have structure like this

```
Array1 = [@"title1",@"head1",@"body1"];
Array2 = [@"title2",@"head2",@"body2"];
Array3 = [@"title3",@"head3",@"body3"];
```

Now you need to include this array inside another array which will contain all the 3 arrays , like this

```
mainArray = [array1,array2,array3];
```

Now you can write down your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSArray *currentArray = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//here you have the array array1 for row 1,respectively.
cell.title = currentArray[0];//as title is at first index
cell.head = currentArray[1];//as head is at second index
cell.description = currentArray[2];//as description is at third index

return cell;

}
```

P.S - It is better to construct your mainArray as an array of dictionaries like this

```
mainArray = @[dic1,dic2,dic3];
```

and each dictionary as this

```
   dic1 = @{@"title":@"titleTextString",@"description":@"descriptionTextString",@"head":@"headTextString"}
```

as you can match the keys of this dictionary in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Then your method would look like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *currentDic = [mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//here you have the array array1 for row 1,respectively.
cell.title = [currentDic objectForKey:@"title"]
cell.head = [currentDic objectForKey:@"head"];
cell.description = [currentDic objectForKey:@"description"];

return cell;

}
```

For both the methods your `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` would look like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
    return mainArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3;
}
```